# cmake Xcode generator uses -O0 in release mode instead -O3 or -O2

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

### Background

I have some big multi platform C++ project, which runs on Windows/MacOS/Linux (msvc/clang/clang).
Since project is quite big I'm unable to provide [mcve]. I was trying and such example builds with `-O3` flag.

For MacOS project is build in this way:

```sh
mkdir build_release
cd build_release
cmake -G Xcode -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
cmake --build . --config Release -j 8
```

cmake

```sh
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.19.6

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

clang

```sh
$ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Xcode 12.4 (12D4e)

### Problem

In build logs I've noticed that `-O0` is used instead `-O3` or `-O2`!!!

So I've inspected my CMakeLists.txt files to find explanation:

```sh
$ git grep -E "CMAKE_C(XX)?_FLAGS"
CMake/build_flags_override.cmake:    init_and_replace_flags(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MDd" "/MTd")
CMake/build_flags_override.cmake:    init_and_replace_flags(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MD" "/MT")
CMake/build_flags_override.cmake:    init_and_replace_flags(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/MD" "/MT")
CMake/build_flags_override.cmake:    init_and_replace_flags(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MDd" "/MTd")
CMake/build_flags_override.cmake:    init_and_replace_flags(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MD" "/MT")
CMake/build_flags_override.cmake:    init_and_replace_flags(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "/MD" "/MT")
CMake/macostools.cmake:        set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fobjc-arc" PARENT_SCOPE)
CMake/macostools.cmake:        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fobjc-arc" PARENT_SCOPE)
CMakeLists.txt:    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} -g -DNDEBUG")
CMakeLists.txt:    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -g -DNDEBUG")
CMakeLists.txt:        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /bigobj")
```

So optimization levels where not tweaked.

All targets (except one) are regular cmake targets (no spatial configuration default settings are used). The only one which is different is configured like this:

```
add_executable(MyTarget)

set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME "Product name"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME "Product name"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${PRODUCT_CONFIGURATION_DIR}/Info.plist
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}.0"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_LONG_VERSION_STRING "Product name v${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}.0"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING "${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}.0"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER "com.product.identifier"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_COPYRIGHT "(C) ${EI_CURRENT_YEAR} Company name"
    MACOSX_RPATH TRUE
    MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER com.product.identifier
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS "@loader_path/Libraries"
    RESOURCE "${RESOURCE_FILES}"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME TRUE
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY ""
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_EXECUTABLE_NAME "exe_name"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT[variant=Release] dwarf-with-dsym
)
```

What is more annoying adding explicitly `-O3` to `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` doesn't change situation.

I have no clues what happen. I'm sure couple months ago it was fine now optimizations are disabled. I do not know problem was caused by software update or some change in `CMakeList.txt`.

I would like to avoid git binary search, since configuration process is quite time consuming (git submodules are involved).

### Question

Does anyone have a clue what could be source of this problem and/or how to overcome it?

### Clues

It is fine on Windows and Linux.

When I use default generator on MacOS (`make`) instead `-G Xcode` proper optimization flag is used (`-O3`). I would be happy with that, but in this case `cmake` is unable to utilize `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_*` properties set on final target and this doesn't meat my requirements.

Comment: "Since project is quite big I'm unable to provide [mcve]." - Having a big project absolutely doesn't prevent from providing [mcve]. In the title you claims that it is XCode who uses `-O0`: this can be easily checked with the simple project which just has `add_executable` call without additional settings.

Comment: I was trying to provide [mcve] and such example builds with `-O3` flag. I'm keep trying to reproduce it in small project, but it is hard to spot detail which could cause this in large project. And if I could reproduce it then most probably I could fix it.

Comment: I've showed what are relevant cmake variables and how they are modified. I've point out that with different generator it just works. So I'm hoping someone else can have a clue what else could cause this weird behavior, or hoping someone will ask proper question.

Comment: Aside `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` there are other ways for specify compiler flags (e.g. `target_compile_options` command or `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property). Also, it is possible that the variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is changed **indirectly**, by the name which is contained in the other variable. As for debugging, I would suggest to find location of `-O0` in the command line and to check **nearest** options. You could get an idea where these nearest options come from, so you could inspect these locations for `-O0`.

Comment: This are some clues. Sadly `target_compile_options` and `COMPILE_OPTIONS` are not used in project anywhere.

Comment: Could setting `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT` cause XCode to add `-O0`?

Comment: If you are going to add "-g" to the Release flags, why not use RelWithDebInfo instead?

Answer (score 0):

Problem turn out to be an order.

I just moved this part:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} -g -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -g -DNDEBUG")
```

to the bottom of `CMakeLists.txt` and everything works as it suppose to.

I noticed that in location where it was originally (before change) value of `$CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` was empty. When I moved statements to bottom original value of `$CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` (before my change) contains `-O3`.

I have no idea what is between those two location which could have this effect. There is nothing between those two places which explicitly changes this variables.